# Splitting Pandas DF converts it into list

Tags: python, pandas

Here's my dataframe

[image: Pandas Data Frame]

In Cover Design column there are few values that end with "- undefined" and I want to remove that. So, I used split function to remove

```
test[['ttt']] = test['Cover Design'].str.split(' - undefined')
```

and this is what I got

[image]

But the values in new column are in list type how to get it to string?

Comment: `test['Cover Design'].str.replace(' - undefined','')` why not just replace with nothing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your solution should be changed for `str[0]` for select first values of lists after `split`:

```
test['ttt'] = test['Cover Design'].str.split(' - undefined').str[0]
```

Another solution is use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
test['ttt'] = test['Cover Design'].str.replace(' - undefined', '')
```

If need specify end of string by regex `$`:

```
test['ttt'] = test['Cover Design'].str.replace(' - undefined$', '')
```

---

Bad solution is use `strip`, because it remove all values from `- undefined` from end and start of string, dont use it:

```
test['ttt'] = test['Cover Design'].str.strip(' - undefined')
```

Comment: Thanks bud, I think I asked this question too soon, I should've tried.

Comment: BTW @jezrael where can I find you on social netwrok? LinkedIn/ Twitter?

Comment: @Vijayaraghavan - I dont use it, only email - from my profile (only run code)